PHP - Issue when adding a return type declaration for a parent class
I have currently have the following classes:
class Textarea Extends Field {}

class Field {}

I'm trying to declare a return type for the following function
public function field(string $field): Field
{

}

I would like the 'Textarea' class to be returnable via the field function and my understanding is that because the child class has a parent class of 'Field' then this should work?
I'm currently receiving the following error:
App\AdminCrud\CrudModel::field(): Return value must be of type ?App\AdminCrud\Field, App\AdminCrud\Fields\Textarea returned


This seems to work fine - demo: https://3v4l.org/40Xst . What version of PHP are you running? And where exactly does this error come from? Is it a runtime error in PHP, or some report from your IDE? Have you actually attempted to run any code which uses this function declaration?

This works perfectly fine? Although, variance is not even needed here, just return static... which is inherently a dervied type of Field as thus could be therefore accepted as an argument of Field....

Also, are you sure the code you've shown us here is the same code which is causing the error? Maybe double-check...

Make sure that you imported the Field type (with use) in the code where you're using it in that field() method. If not, php will assume the Field you're referring to in the return type is in the same namespace as the calling class.
